# R tells me that shapefile does not exist

Tags: r, shapefile

I have several shapefiles (inside zipfiles) in my directory which I can open using (eg)

```
tweed<-st_read(dsn="C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/PhD Oct 22/21009.shp")
```

-- no problem there.

But I have downloaded a shapefile of GB outline from https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/great-britain-shapefile
and it's stored in exactly the same way as the files which I can use.  But when I try to read this in I get an error message:

```
gb<-st_read(dsn="C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/PhD Oct 22/gb_1km.shp")
Error: Cannot open "C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/PhD Oct 22/gb_1km.shp"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
```

As far as I can see the gb file is exactly the same kind of thing as the other working files...  Can anyone explain this?  Thanks Nick Wray

Comment: Shapefiles are typically a collection of ~5 files. Are all the correct files present in the repository? maybe you missed copying one?

Comment: What does `list.files(path = "C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/PhD Oct 22/", pattern = "gb_1km")` return?

Comment: And does `file.access` indicate you have the necessary permissions to access the file(s).